# Automating the change in the Hyperlink of PowerPoint Shape in the Actions Menu

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have 50 shapes in Slide 1 named `1`,`2`...`50`.
I want them to hyperlink to the slide number of the shape name.

`1`: Select the shape go to `Insert > Action > Hyperlink to > Slide... >  Slide 1`

`5`: Select the shape go to `Insert > Action > Hyperlink to > Slide... >  Slide 1`

I can automate this by having a macro play on click of the shape

```
Sub GotoReqdSlide(oSh As Shape)
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide Int(oSh.Name)
End Sub
```

However, I'm looking for a solution that would allow the hyperlinks to work even when macros are disabled. I tried automating the hyperlink process of `Insert > Action > Hyperlink to > Slide... >  Slide 1` using the following code but it didn't work out.

[image]

```
For i = 1 To 50
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(i).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink = "Slide " & i
Next i
```

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim pp As Presentation
Set pp = ActivePresentation

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 50
    With pp.Slides(3).Shapes(i).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = pp.Slides(i).SlideNumber & _
                                ". " & _
                                pp.Slides(i).Name
    End With
Next i
```